# Notepad++: Mark a word, and then replace ALL words with [word]

Tags: notepad++, replace

basicly i want to mark ONE word in a text, and then replace with a single click or hotkey all matched words with brackets [[]].

lets say i mark the word bus. what i want is that all bus words in the text transfer to [[bus]].

Its a wiki text, which im editing in notepad++

What i recorded a macro (mark text, ctrl+x, [[, ctrl+v, ]]) which only marks the marked word with brackets

i tried regular expressions like:

find: bus
replace: [[\1]] but all i get is [[]].

i think my mistake is very simpel, but i cant find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a matching group to your regex, e.g., Find: `(bus)` Replace: `[[\1]]`.

---

If you are ok with installing and using the [Python Script](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) plugin, you can pretty easily accomplish what you want. Here's an example script which will replace the selected text with the selected text surrounded by brackets:

```
editor.beginUndoAction()

selected = editor.getSelText()
if selected:
    editor.replace(selected, '[[' + selected + ']]')

editor.endUndoAction()
```

The only caveat to this is that it seems to be applied across all open files.

Save that to a script (I called it "Wikify Text.py") in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\config\PythonScript\scripts`. The plugin can then be used to map this to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thank you, i knew it is simpel.

Any Idea to lay this on a shortcut?

for example:

mark the word, hit alt+a = all marked words have double brackets

Comment: When i try to record a macro of these actions (mark the word, ctrl+c, ctrl+h, ctrl+v, klick replace all) it wont work

Comment: @Labamba: I tried to setup something as a macro, but I could only get it to work with the word I selected when recording the macro, e.g., I recorded a macro selecting and replacing `bus` with `[[bus]]`, and it worked, but only for the word bus.